# Grabbing video dimensions by Regex from a string?

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to grab the dimensions of a video from a string produced by ffmpeg's output in .net, the dimensions i'm trying to obtain by regex are basically like this 1080x960 320x264 etc..

I've found many articles over this subject but none of this worked for me and sadly i'm no regex expert so i couldn't edit their code.. The code that i'm trying to edit and can't work looks like this if it gives you any insight;

```
   Match c = Regex .Match (ffmpegOutputString,"\\s(\\d+)[xX](\\d+)\\s");
   int w=int.Parse ( c.Groups[1].Value );
   int h=int.Parse ( c.Groups[2].Value );
```

And the string i need to parse is this;

```
   Video: wmv3 (Main), yuv420p, 360x264, 400 kb/s, PAR 1:1
```

With my basic regex knowledge it seems ok to me but it can't grab anything, even i give it an empty string as an input the result is the same, the c.count is 1 and the value is empty string.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the string you need to parse, there is a comma directly after the `360x264`. Your regex is `"\\s(\\d+)[xX](\\d+)\\s"`. The `\\s` matches a whitespace character like a space or tab. Try removing the trailing `\\s` from the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You were close with your regex.  The reason it is not matching is because of the \s on the beginning and the end.  Your parse string has a space in front, but not at the end, and so it won't match.

Also, having (\d) instead of \d would cause the individual numbers to match so I removed the paren.

> Try using this regex: \d+[xX]\d+

I tested it at [RegExLib](http://www.regexlib.com/) which is a great reference for working with regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you also! You've just missed it by 2 minutes i've accepted kevlars answer but i've tried both of your answers and definitely do your suggestions! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: I like this answer better because it's simpler